# Angular Service "Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Hello I can't figure out how to return the correct function / part of the service since it's paignating because of the Yammer API.

I've read documentation and tried returning the whole function but I've spent so long on it I'm starting to despair, please help me.

The return is in the wrong place I think - I get the error:

```
"Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference"
```

My Controller

```
app.controller("mainController", function($scope, $http, yammerREST) {

    $scope.getYammerPosts = function () {
                yammerREST.getYammerData($scope.yammerURL).then(function(data) {
                        $scope.results = data.results;
                });
    };
});
```

My service

```
app.service("yammerREST", function($http) {
    this.getYammerData = function(url) {

        var groupID = url.split("feedId=")[1];
        console.log(groupID);
        var baseURL = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/" + groupID + ".json?threaded=true";
        var url = baseURL;
        var results = [];

        getPosts();

        function getPosts () {
        return $http({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
             }).then(function(response) {
                    results = results.concat(response.data.messages);
                    console.log(results);

                    if (response.data.meta.older_available == true) {
                            url = baseURL + "&older_than=" + results[results.length-1].id;
                            getPosts();
                    };

                    return {
                        yammerListName: response.data.meta.feed_name,
                        results: results,
                    };
            }).catch(function(e){
                console.log("Error: ", e);
            });
        };
    };
});
```

Comment: If I read correctly, I think your getYammerData method, does not return the $http promise. It may miss a close bracket maybe. Or a return before `getPosts();` ?

Comment: It seems you returning getYammerData and not  $http or getPost() methods which returns a promise.

Comment: The `getPosts` function is being called recursively but has no recursion variable. To do effective recursion, `f(x)` has to call `f(x+1)` until some end condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference”

That error message usually means the function failed to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the promise:

```
app.service("yammerREST", function($http) {
    this.getYammerData = function(url) {

        var groupID = url.split("feedId=")[1];
        console.log(groupID);
        var baseURL = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/" + groupID + ".json?threaded=true";
        var startURL = baseURL;
        var results = [];

        //vvvv RETURN promise
        return getPosts(baseURL,startURL);

        function getPosts (baseURL, url) {
            //vvvv RETURN promise
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
            }).then(function(response) {
                    results = results.concat(response.data.messages);
                    console.log(results);

                    if (response.data.meta.older_available == true) {
                        var nextURL = baseURL + "&older_than=" + results[results.length-1].id;
                        //vvvv RETURN promise
                        return getPosts(baseURL,nextURL);
                    };

                    return {
                        yammerListName: response.data.meta.feed_name,
                        results: results,
                    };
            }).catch(function(e){
                console.log("Error: ", e);
                //IMPORTANT to re-throw error
                throw e;
            });
        };
    };
});
```

The `getPosts` function is being called recursively. To do effective recursion, f(x) has to call f(x+1) until some end condition is met.

Also in `.catch` blocks it is important to [re-throw errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in order to skip subsequent `.then` blocks in the promise chain.